# Firebase Storage Download URL Before Posting to Firebase Database Reference

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

Working on an angular 4 project with firebase.

I am struggling to work out how to guarantee that a result has been returned from an Observable before running the next step.

I know that you can’t guarantee that with an Observable because the whole point is it is a stream of data, hence my dilema.

I am trying to upload an image to firebase storage, retrieve its download URL **before** run an update to a firebase database.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**Register User Service**

```
$key: string;
    downloadUrl: string;
    currentUser: any;
    loginId: string;

    constructor(
        private db: AngularFireDatabase,
        private firebaseUploadService: FirebaseUploadService,
        private authService: AuthService) {
        this.firebaseUploadService.currentUrl.subscribe(url => this.downloadUrl = url);
    }

registerUser(firebaseRef: string, user: UserModel): Observable<any> {

        // Create a separate object for file upload with the file passed via the entity
        const file = Object.assign(<UploadModel>{}, user.imagePath);
        user.$key = this.authService.currentUserId;

        return this.firebaseUploadService.pushUpload(user.$key, file).switchMap(upload => {
            console.log('upload returned from service: ', upload)
            user.imagePath = this.downloadUrl;
            return Observable.fromPromise(this.db.object(firebaseRef + '/' + user.$key).update(user));
        });
    }
```

**Firebase Upload Service**

```
    currentUser: any;
    uploads: FirebaseListObservable<UploadModel[]>;

    private urlSource = new BehaviorSubject('http://saveabandonedbabies.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/default.png');
    currentUrl = this.urlSource.asObservable();

    constructor() {
    }

pushUpload(firebaseRef: string, upload: UploadModel): any {

        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${firebaseRef}/${upload.file.name}`).put(upload.file);

        uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
            (snapshot) => {
                // upload in progress
                upload.progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
            },
            (error) => {
                // upload failed
                console.log(error)
            },
            () => {
                // upload success
                upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
                this.urlSource.next(upload.url)
                upload.name = upload.file.name
            }
        );
        return this.urlSource;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all Firebase calls are asynchronous you cant get the download url synchronously. But there is a cheat you can do it using promises.

Try refactoring your code as below :

pushUpload(firebaseRef: string, upload: UploadModel): any {

```
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${firebaseRef}/${upload.file.name}`).put(upload.file);

    uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
        (snapshot) => {
            // upload in progress
            upload.progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        },
        (error) => {
            // upload failed
            console.log(error)
        },
        () => {
            // upload success
            upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
            this.urlSource.next(upload.url)
            upload.name = upload.file.name
          user.imagePath = this.downloadUrl;
    // Place your http request inside a firebase event
        return Observable.fromPromise(this.db.object(firebaseRef + '/' + user.$key).update(user));
        }
    );
    return this.urlSource;
}
```

This might work